# Searching one file from list in second file with Python

Tags: python, search, text

this is my first time posting here and I'm just learning python so please bear with me.
I've had a good look on here and elsewhere on-line trying to find an answer to this, but alas, the web seems bereft!

I have a log file that is generated every day and can contain a number of errors with different syntax.  Some of them are important and others are negligible but due to the fact they all contain the text "Error" I can't just search for the one word.

I have a list of the text of the errors from when they were previously seen in one file, and I want to compare the log file against it for matches so that it warns if any of them are seen.

I have managed to get it working for a single error, but I can't get it to work for the list.

The code that work is as follows:

```
    log_file = open ('a file location' , 'r')
    read_file = file.read ()
    search = read_file.find ('Error type 1 happened at x')
    if search != -1:
        print 'Error found in  log at point ' + str((search)) + '!!!'
    else :
        print "All is good!!!  :-D "
```

For the list, I have tried the following:

```
    load_log_file = open ('a file location' , 'r')
    read_log_file = load_log_file.read ()

    def txt_search (read_log_file):
        errors = open ('another file location' , 'r')
    for error in errors.readlines() :
            if error.strip ('\r\n') in read_log_file:
                return 'Error found in log !!!'
            else :
                return "All is good!!!  :-D "

    print txt_search (read_log_file)
```

I am getting a result when this is run, but it always comes back with "All is good".
I'm probably missing something really obvious but any help will be greatly received.

Many thanks

Comment: It would be best if you could also post an example log file (a few lines) and also if you started off working on that short example expanding as you continue getting some results. good start is to open your files in `rU` mode (`U` stand for universal line ending) and when you strip do that using `'line'.strip(os.linesep)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're prematurely returning.

```
load_log_file = open ('a file location' , 'r')
read_log_file = load_log_file.read ()

def txt_search (read_log_file):
    errors = open ('another file location' , 'r')
    for error in errors.readlines() :
        if error.strip ('\r\n') in read_log_file:
            return 'Error found in log !!!'

    return "All is good!!!  :-D "

print txt_search (read_log_file)
```

What happens in your original code is that it looks for the first error, doesn't find it, and then returns "All is good". Always remember that a `return` statement ends the function.

Comment: @BobHoward: Don't worry, we all screw up like this now and then. Wither you didn't know about `return` (in which case, _learn_!). Or you did, and you just forgot (happened to me a million times). Just plod on :)